# Xcode: Custom build configurations in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to get SPM to work with different build configurations other than `Debug` and `Release`. Our iOS project has different schemes (e.g. Debug-Staging, Debug-Production, Alpha-Staging, Alpha-Production, etc.) where I set the bundle identifier, some flags, etc.

Is there a way to achieve that diversification even if SPM only "understands" Debug and Release?

Answer (score 1):

Specify path to your custom config file when invoking generate-xcodeproj command.

**Sample**

```
swift-package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides Config.xcconfig
```